# Restarting Windows 7 breaks grub

Tags: grub2, windows, windows-7, grubrescue, restart

Whenever I restart my computer in Windows through the restart button it brings up grub rescue. I can always fix it with boot repair.
Apprechiate your help!

Comment: I dont even have to do boot repair. I only have to boot up ubuntu from a dvd and it works after.

Comment: Do you mean you wanna boot WIndows, but all you get is grub message?

Comment: @Redbob Just after the post screen grub rescue appears